# The best control strategy to determine the 0 position of a hall sensor linear actuator

Tags: motor, sensor, pid-controller, hall-effect, position

I am using a TA29 Timotion, with hall sensor as a feedback. To determine its position, the actuator should be in position 0, before it starts counting. What is the best way for me to do this without using an external switch?

https://www.timotion.com/en/product/detail/linear-actuators/ta29-series?upcls=1481269298&guid=1535388333

My controller for this is Arduino Mega 2560.

My solution: I retracted the actuator starting up which is when my controller starts counting its position.

Comment: You buy the version that is offered with *internal* limit switches or the one with a potentiometer, or you call/email their applications engineer and discuss your needs.

Comment: I apologize if I explained it vaguely, the actuator do provide limit switch. My problem is that I am not able to have the controller determine the 0 position of the actuator ( fully retracted)

Comment: You determine the zero position by running to the limit switch, that's (at least half of) what it's for.  Then you start counting.

Comment: please do not crosspost ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79406/the-best-control-strategy-to-determine-the-0-position-of-a-hall-sensor-linear-ac

Comment: Yes but to determine this, the controller needs a signal am I right? The actuator just cuts of the current which cant be detected by the controller (i.e. arduino)

Comment: Why can't your controller detect the actuator current?

Comment: Typically limit switches are signals to the controller, one would not normally run motor power through them.  The exception would be where there is no controller.

Comment: Run the actuator in *open loop* with signal of appropriate polarity until it hits the limits switch. **Then** switch on the controller. With this scheme, the position is zeroed when the control is switched on.